Asyncio Streams server detecting disconnection
I am rewriting an older server using Streams, and one of the problems I never manage to solve was the disconnection issue.
I have made this really simple server example:
import asyncio

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    address = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print(f"Connection: {address}")

    try:
        while True:
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                print(f"Disconnected: {address}.")
                break
            print(f"{address} Send: {data.decode()}")

            writer.write('\n'.encode())
            await writer.drain()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Something bad happened: {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"Closed: {address}")
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '0.0.0.0', 5678)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())

If I connect using netcat, everything works, if I close the netcat or the terminal, it knows the connection has ended. But if I disconnect my client network, it will never know that my client is offline. I know this is a lower level limitation, but I am thinking in ways to solve this.
Currently, my best approach was using a timeout for force a disconnection, like this example:
import asyncio

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    address = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print(f"Connection: {address}")

    try:
        while True:
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(1024), timeout=10.0)
            if not data:
                print(f"Disconnected: {address}.")
                break
            print(f"{address} Send: {data.decode()}")

            writer.write('\n'.encode())
            await writer.drain()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print(f"Timeout: {address}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Something bad happened: {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"Closed: {address}")
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '0.0.0.0', 5678)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())

This works, but I would need to fine-tune my application to fit all devices (and unfortunately, most of those devices that send me data were build in a time that you paid per byte send, so their keep alive interval is ridiculous long).
Is there a better way to know when there was a disconnection without needing to wait several minutes for a timeout?
Thank you for your attention.

I found a way manipulating the socket behaviour. I am not exactly sure what this does (yet), but all my tests worked.
import asyncio
import socket

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    address = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print(f"Connection: {address}")

    # Enable TCP keepalive on the socket
    sock = writer.get_extra_info('socket')
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)

    try:
        while True:
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                print(f"Disconnected: {address}.")
                break
            print(f"{address} Send: {data.decode()}")

            writer.write('\n'.encode())
            await writer.drain()
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(f"Timeout: {address}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception {address}: {e}")
    finally:
        if not writer.is_closing():
            print(f"Closed: {address}")
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '0.0.0.0', 8888)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())

The if not writer.is_closing(): part is important. Without it, you will get another Exception inside the finally trying to close the already close writer.

Detecting lost connection is not a problem specific to asyncio or Python in general. Using the TCP keepalive feature is the right thing to do, but your timing is way too aggressive. Linux defaults are: retry intvl = 75 sec., probe count = 9, time = 7200 sec.  = 2 hours (source: man tcp) Those might look too relaxed, but keep in mind that 1. lost connection is an exception (crashed OS, cut cable, etc.) 2. you don't want to react to some temporary network glitches 3. the overhead should be minimal
